# Copy a folder from shared drive to another folder using vbscripting

Tags: vbscript

I want to write a script

where script can check user home drive(\\server1\home$\user1) path in active directory and go to that path to cut "user1" folder from (\\server1\home$\user1) and paste in (\\server1\home$\Leavers Archive)

There are 7 home drives servers and about 100 users.

Help on this will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If Vbscript is your only choice then you need to look into 
using the filesystem object. (fso)